# Love Live without the music

Tags: love-live-school-idol-festival

I'm playing love live game mostly for the management and the story. Is there a way to turn off the horrendous music mini-game that's forced on you all the time? Is there a version without it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you hate the music minigame in Love Live! School Idol Festival, there's no way around it.  It's an integral part of the game, and there's not a version that doesn't contain it.